# Is there a way to show a test count or summary for all tests in glib test framework?

Tags: unit-testing, glib

I want to know how many tests passed and how many tests failed.
All I get so far is long list of tests with an "OK" next to their name. This was fine until I had so many tests they go outside the console.

All I need is test count or at least a message saying "all tests passed". It has happened more than once already that I missed an error report due to this.

I have checked the [g_test_init](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Testing.html#g-test-init) function parameters and I'm tempted to say that the answer is no. I just find it hard to believe that a testing framework so old and used doesn't have this simple feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hurts a little to suggest this, but:

```
./run-tests && echo "All tests passed"
```

Test executables *should* return `EXIT_SUCCESS` on success and `EXIT_FAILURE` if any tests failed.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of GLib, test executables accept a `--tap` option which prints [TAP](http://testanything.org/) output. It is meant to integrate with other utilities such as Automake that can parse TAP. (TAP is simple enough that you can easily write your own parser if need be.)